# How to set a timeout for a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a requirement that I have to give xx ms to execute a function. After xx ms I have to abort that function. Please help me how to implement it in C.

Answer (score 18):

I think the nicest way to do this involves pthreads.  Start the calculation that potentially may need to be cancelled in its own thread, and in the main thread use pthread_cond_timedwait:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* for ETIMEDOUT */
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_mutex_t calculating = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t done = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *expensive_call(void *data)
{
        int oldtype;

        /* allow the thread to be killed at any time */
        pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &oldtype);

        /* ... calculations and expensive io here, for example:
         * infinitely loop
         */
        for (;;) {}

        /* wake up the caller if we've completed in time */
        pthread_cond_signal(&done);
        return NULL;
}

/* note: this is not thread safe as it uses a global condition/mutex */
int do_or_timeout(struct timespec *max_wait)
{
        struct timespec abs_time;
        pthread_t tid;
        int err;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&calculating);

        /* pthread cond_timedwait expects an absolute time to wait until */
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &abs_time);
        abs_time.tv_sec += max_wait->tv_sec;
        abs_time.tv_nsec += max_wait->tv_nsec;

        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, expensive_call, NULL);

        /* pthread_cond_timedwait can return spuriously: this should
         * be in a loop for production code
         */
        err = pthread_cond_timedwait(&done, &calculating, &abs_time);

        if (err == ETIMEDOUT)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: calculation timed out\n", __func__);

        if (!err)
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&calculating);

        return err;
}

int main()
{
        struct timespec max_wait;

        memset(&max_wait, 0, sizeof(max_wait));

        /* wait at most 2 seconds */
        max_wait.tv_sec = 2;
        do_or_timeout(&max_wait);

        return 0;
}
```

you can compile and run this on linux with:

```
$ gcc test.c -pthread -lrt && ./a.out
do_or_timeout: calculation timed out
```

Comment: The end of your `do_or_timeout` is concerning to me. If I call this function multiple times from my main function and it times out on the first call, will it ever get the lock back? It looks like the lock is only released if no timeout occurred.

Comment: I would provide a pointer signal to do_or_timeout and while loop based on this signal which will be controlled by the parent thread whenever the timeout occurs thus the child thread can have a chance to exit gracefully

Comment: It's crucial to add process of converting nanoseconds to seconds after you add max_wait to abs_time for such cases when current timestamp in nanoseconds part is big enough to make a full second after you add your timeout:
`while(abs_time.tv_nsec >= 1000000000L) { abs_time.tv_sec += 1; abs_time.tv_nsec -= 1000000000L; } `
If you don't do so, occasionally you will get timeout even in cases where normally it wouldn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
->include time.h 
->take two variable for start time & current time of type time_t
like time_t start_time,current_time
-> take start time 
   time(&start_time);
now in while loop continuisly check for 
   time(&current_time)
   difftime(current_time,start_time)
if difftime's return value is 15ms break while loop & close your program
```

Comment: if you still not getting my tips then say me i will give you complete code for this ..when i get time..!!

Comment: I think what he wants is to make sure that a function finishes execution within a certain timeframe, while not placing this time logic in the function itself.

Comment: -1. How does this solve the problem? If there's a call inside your while loop that takes 30 minutes, it will not halt execution till that function returns.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim devi hasnt specify that he wants to do something in that function so i havent care for that but thanks for pointing out that bug..i need to re-think for this whole design..!! What should be the solution in that case?

Comment: The question title is "how to set timeout for a *function*". I'd probably approach this using a watchdog thread and a main thread to run the actual function similar to the way Bobby Powers has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using pthreads you can also do a similar timeout function using the Apache Portable Runtime: http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__thread__proc.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "apr.h"
#include "apr_thread_proc.h"
#include "apr_time.h"

void *APR_THREAD_FUNC expensive_call(apr_thread_t *thread, void *data)
{
    (void)thread;
    bool *done = data;

    /* ... calculations and expensive io here, for example:
     * infinitely loop
     */
    for (;;) {}

    // signal caller that we are done
    *done = true;
    return NULL;
}

bool do_or_timeout(apr_pool_t *pool, apr_thread_start_t func, int max_wait_sec)
{
    apr_thread_t *thread;
    bool thread_done = false;
    apr_thread_create(&thread, NULL, func, &thread_done, pool);
    apr_time_t now = apr_time_now();
    for (;;) {
        if (thread_done) {
            apr_thread_join(NULL, thread);
            return true;
        }
        if (apr_time_now() >= now + apr_time_make(max_wait_sec, 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        // avoid hogging the CPU in this thread
        apr_sleep(10000);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // initialize APR
    apr_initialize();
    apr_pool_t *ap;
    if (apr_pool_create(&ap, NULL) != APR_SUCCESS) {
        exit(127);
    }

    // try to do the expensive call; wait up to 3 seconds
    bool completed = do_or_timeout(ap, expensive_call, 3);
    if (completed) {
        printf("expensive_call completed\n");
    } else {
        printf("expensive_call timed out\n");
    }

    apr_terminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile using a command like this

gcc -o example example.c -lapr-1

Answer (score 1):

I do not know that architecture so I can give you only a general hint. I would try something similar to old Symbian TRAP mechanism.

1. In the main routine:

   - start a timer.
   - put away a stack pointer
   - put away a program counter.
   - call your function.
2. In timer exception (interrupt) handling routine.
   This is a bit tricky because you need to know where in given architecture stack pointers and program counters are kept (processor's datasheet) when exception handling kicks in. Program counter was most likely pushed to the main routine stack.
   So  your steps are:

   - replace the stack pointer value (for main routine) with your copied value.
   - replace the program counter value with your copied value + offset (because you want to return to execution after your function call - best to check the assembly code to be sure how big is it).
   - return from exception (interrupt) handling routine.

Comment: According to Renas V850 Architecture datasheet PC is store in EIPC register.

Comment: Yeah but this is true but only if you don't call any other functions from within that function. Sorry I haven't seen v850 series and Renesas compiler in my life so this is as much as I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

@Bobby Powers answer is work, but need a little change as below

```
if (!err)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&calculating);
-> change to 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&calculating);
as @T.D. Smith says

and need add  
pthread_cancel(tid) // if isn't add, the expensive_call may never exit if your function couldn't exit by itself, such as for (;;) {} or something block operation.
```