# Implementing execution timeout with C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, timeout, execution

I've been thinking about implementing an execution timeout mechanism in my code. I browsed looking for advice but all I saw is implementing execution timeouts for other programs being called, which wasn't exactly my idea.

I'm working with C/C++ on Linux.

What's the best way to accomplish this without using external libraries? I thought that maybe running a separate thread that upon timeout, sends a TERM signal to the process ID and then the program handles it and exits, but I don't know if it's correct in terms of good practice.

How would you implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on what code you want to limit. If it's your own code, it's better to add support for timeouts to the code itself. Post your real code, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: It's a very simple code, all it does is read some files and parse arguments. It's not very interesting but I can post it if it is necessary.

Comment: What I want to limit is the time since the program is called until some amount of seconds have passed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) on Linux to get a SIGVTALRM after a given amount of time

This is how you would set up a timer :

```
#include <sys/time.h>

/* Start a timer that expires after 2.5 seconds */
struct itimerval timer;
timer.it_value.tv_sec = 2;
timer.it_value.tv_usec = 500000;
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &timer, 0);
```

Note that the default handler for SIGVTALRM will terminate your program with an error. 
It will technically work, but if you want to handle it cleanly you can install a signal handler like this :

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void timer_handler (int signum)
{
    printf ("Timed out!\n");
}

/* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
struct sigaction sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
sigaction (SIGVTALRM, &sa, 0);
```

Of course this will only work on Linux (and perhaps on Mac/BSD).

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to stop the program at timeout using pthreads (as you have described yourself) is a very good idea. There are a few threads on stackoverflow with similar problems so i suggest you look at their answers, for example: [How to set a timeout for a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738546/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-function-in-c)