# Interrupt a function inside a main loop after a certain amount of time

Tags: c, timeout, signals

I have a main loop, and I have a function that displays a menu with some choices and waits for user's input.
The point is that I also have to check if a new event occures *--in my specific case, a new message is received, but this isn't relevant at all--* and I can't wait the user to make an action: I have to implement a timeout for that function.

Here is a simple example of what I'm talking about:

```
int choice;

for(;;){

    /* a new message could be arrived and we should read it now ... */

    choice = menu_function();

    /* 
       ...but the user still hasn't made an action,
       so the menu_function() hasn't returned yet.
    */

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So far I thought of using `fork()` before the `menu_function()` and `kill()` this process after it received a `SIGALRM` signal through `alarm()`, but I don't think this is the proper solution since it's inside a loop.

What kind of solution should I adopt?

P.S. I don't think this is a duplicate since, as I already said, the function interrupting request is inside a loop. Or at least for me, I think it's a different thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a timeout for a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738546/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention `fork` I assume you're on a POSIX system (like Linux or macOS)?

That means you can install a signal handler for `SIGALRM` in the process doing the waiting, and the reception of the signal should interrupt the blocking operation (with `errno == EINTR`) which you can check for and have the `menu_function` return a value meaning "exit". The code in your loop could then check for this value and `break` out of the loop.

Another alternative is to not use the standard C input functions unless there's actually something to read. You can do this by using the `select` call with the desired timeout, and poll `FILENO_STDIN`. If the `select` function returns with a timeout, again let `menu_function` return a special value meaning "exit", else it will use the standard C function to read and parse the input.

No need to fork new processes for either the input-handler or the timer.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. I'll try and let you know!

Comment: sorry but I think I didn't understand well. How can I return a value from the `menu_function` when it receives `SIGALRM`? I mean, I wrote a `handle_sigalrm` function but I don't know what to do with this. Also, I didn't pay attention when you mentioned `break`: where should I use it? If you could make an example --just filling my example with the right code-- I would certainly mark your answer as solution, but for now I'm still stuck...

Comment: @UrbiJr When you use e.g. `scanf` it will somewhere be stuck on a `read` call, waiting for characters to arrive on standard input. When you get `SIGALRM` then the `read` call will be interrupted and if the signal was initialized to not restart the interrupted function then `read` will return with an error and `errno` set to `EINTR`. This will be passed up to the `scanf` function which in turn will return `EOF` to you. If your `menu_function` calls `scanf` it can check for this condition and return. The signal handler itself doesn't have to do anything at all, its body can be empty.

Comment: ok but what if I use `wgetch` (from ncurses) instead of a simple `scanf`? It has same behaviour and same return values when `SIGALRM` is received?

Comment: @UrbiJr It still needs to use `read` somewhere, but with ncurses it complicates things as it changes the flags of the terminal and how the terminal returns data etc. My suggestion is that you experiment: Make a simple test program with the same ncurses settings as your actual program, set up a signal handler, and then use `wgetch` to read a character and see what happens when the signal fires.

Comment: man I solved by using `wtimeout` ncurses function that sets a delay for a specific window input and blocks until it is reached. I'm now aware that maybe I should have mentioned ncurses in my question, and probably I would have solved my problem much earlier. However, your answer is related to the question I made so I have to mark it as the solution

Comment: @UrbiJr Terrific! :) And while I appreciate the accept, I don't really deserve it since my answer didn't actually help with the problem. If you found it useful then just a simple up-vote is enough, but it's okay to not accept it.